# Can I get reviews or stars for hotels or restaurants in HERE Geocoding & Search API?

Tags: here-api, heremaps

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation ([link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-browse-brief.html)), but the previous version of the Places API ([link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/search-results-ranking.html)) said:

> Certain types of categories, such as restaurants or hotels, are ranked via a "recommendations-style" algorithm where measures of popularity or quality, such as number of stars or reviews, are taken into account.

Does that mean that I would be able to retrieve info on number of starts for a hotel or ratings for restaurants?

Answer (score 0):

Rating is Rich content. Rich content is not covered within the base or extended content and is generally provided by third-party data
suppliers.

See more on references from Geocoding and Search API 7 Discover API here https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-discover-brief.html